# Is there a way to make my 1D random walk code more time efficient here?

Tags: python, matplotlib, random

So my code plots the average distance from equilibrium of a 1D random walk over 1000 steps. My code works, but takes an inordinate amount of time, I think probably due to the loop inside a loop of the system. Is there a way to make this more efficient or am I stuck with this? Thanks :)

```
nsteps = 1000
ndim = 1
numpy.seterr(invalid="ignore")

for i in range(100):
    w = walker(numpy.zeros(1))
    ys = w.doSteps(nsteps)
    avgpos = []
    
    for i in range(0, len(ys)):
        avgpos.append(sum(ys[:i+1])/i+1)
    
    plt.plot(range(nsteps+1),avgpos)
```

The ys are the results from doing n steps. I'm sure the inefficiency is from something within the loop rather than a problem in the earlier code

Comment: I don't think your code does what you think it does. At the moment, it's creating 100 different plots for each walker, where each plot shows the walker's path, with each data point divided by the number of steps the walker has taken

Comment: First, use `numpy.arange(0, len(ys))`  and `plt.plot(numpy.arange(nsteps+1), avgpos)` instead of `range(...)`

Comment: @dc-ddfe Isn't this the walkers average (mean) position? The sum of all positions divided by the number of positions it's been in?

Comment: @AdamP Sounds about right, but why are you doing it 100 times for 100 different walkers?

Comment: @dc-dffe I was only meant to be doing it 100 tims for one walker (or once per walker). The nwalkers variable was a relic from an earlier attempt, sorry. Have edited it out to make it less confusing.

Comment: @AdamP what does `walker` and `w.doSteps` do?  i.e. why do you think it's the code you've posted and why not put a cut down version into the question?  e.g. does a simple `ys = np.cumsum(np.random.standard_normal(nsteps))` produce the same shape data?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the built in method for doing [cumulative sums](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html).  I'd also suggest fixing the warnings from Numpy, I think you need some brackets around `sum(...)/i+1`. Python, like most languages, would evaluate this as `(sum(...)/i)+1` because division binds more tightly than addition.

A [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would thus be:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nsteps = 1000

for i in range(100):
    ys = np.cumsum(np.random.standard_normal(nsteps))

    avgpos = []
    for i in range(0, len(ys)):
        avgpos.append(sum(ys[:i+1])/(i+1)) #  note brackets

    plt.plot(np.array(avgpos))
```

which takes my laptop ~8 seconds.

I could instead use the Numpy `cumsum` method like this:

```
for i in range(100):
    ys = np.cumsum(np.random.standard_normal(nsteps))

    avgpos = np.cumsum(ys) / (np.arange(nsteps)+1)
    plt.plot(avgpos)
```

which only takes ~0.1 seconds.